# Google API current status of contacts

Tags: google-api, google-talk, google-hangouts

Is there a Google API that returns the current status (available, away, offline) of each of my contacts? I'm referring to the status shown in gtalk in gmail or hangouts from the green, yellow, or gray light? I'm looking to authenticate and then be able to query an API that will return an array of my contacts and their current status. Does an API for this exist?